# Puppeteer / Nodejs Proper function structure, it doesn't seem to be executing

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to learn puppeteer / nodejs.  I've followed some tutorials and have a basic scraper running:
1.  It goes to a website.
2.  Scrolls to the bottom
3.  Creates a pdf.

The website I am trying to scrape has a comments feature (there may or may not be comments on each post).

I've created a function called expandAllComments (code below), but it doesn't seem to do what I am expecting it too, which is expand all the comments.

As I am learning, I am a big fan of console.log statements, and I've put several in my function (this is what I would do in Python, maybe it doesn't apply here).

The main scraper.js has these lines:

```js
async function processSite(browser) {
  console.log("Processing web site")
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://somewebsite.com’ , { waitUntil: ['networkidle2'] })

  //do some scrolling
  await delay(4000);

  try {
  await page.autoScroll()
  } catch (e) 
  {console.log(`Error occurred while scrolling timeline: ${e}`)
  debug(`Error occurred while scrolling timeline: ${e}`)
  }

  await delay(1000)


  await delay(4000)

  //expand all the comments
  try {
    await page.expandAllComments()
    } catch (e) 
    {console.log(`Error occurred while scrolling timeline: ${e}`)
    debug(`Error occurred while scrolling timeline: ${e}`)
    }  
  await delay(2000)

  await page.scrollToTop()


  //save to pdf
  //await page.pdf({ format: 'letter', path: "test.pdf", printBackground: true });  //commented out so I can watch in non-headless mode.  Save to pdf doesn’t work in non-headless


}
```

the expandallcomments(), which is in a helper/plugin file (index.js), has the following files (really heavy on the console.log -- sorry!).

Also, I verified the query selector in console.

```js
async expandAllComments () {

    console.log("This is a print statement from within the expandAllComments function")
    await this.evaluate(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        let link_clicker = () => {
          let lc = 0
          document
            .querySelectorAll('._commentToggle')
            .forEach(el => {
              {
                delay(10000);
                el.click()
                lc++
              }
            })
          return lc
        }

        let timer = setTimeout(function click_links () {
          let links_clicked = link_clicker()
          if (links_clicked) {
            timer = setTimeout(click_links, 1000)
          } else {
            clearTimeout(timer)
            resolve()
          }
        }, 10000)
      })
    })
  }
```

I was expecting that in the resuling pdf file (when I run it in headless mode) that I would see the comments expanded, which doesn't happen.

and, when i watch for console.log output, this is what I see:

```
Processing web site
Waiting before scrolling
Finished Waiting
Scrolling 
This is a print statement from within the autoscroll function
Finished the infinite scrollng.
Waiting before moving on

Waiting before moving on
about to expand comments
This is a print statement from within the expandAllComments function
all comments expanded
About to scroll to top
Scrolled to top
```

Only one of the console.log statements prints from expandAllComments() (maybe this is just nodejs functions work, I'm not sure)

I guess I'm trying to figure out how to make it click on each selector for the comments so they can be included in the pdf.

Thanks in advance!!

**Update**

I tried to simplify and cleanup my code a little and try @md-abu-taher suggestions.

**new code**

```js
//const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const chalk = require("chalk");
const fs = require('fs-extra');
// MY OCD of colorful console.logs for debugging... IT HELPS
const error = chalk.bold.red;
const success = chalk.keyword("green");

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-puppeteer-helper')())

function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    });
 }

async function processSite(browser) {
    console.log("Processing web site")
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('somesite' , { waitUntil: ['networkidle2'] })

    await delay(10000)
    await autoScroll(page);
    await delay(10000)

    console.log("about to look for element")
    const comments = await page.$$('._commentToggleBtn')

    await delay(10000)
    for (let comment of comments) {
        await comment.click()
        console.log("Loop click")
       await page.waitFor(10000)
    }
    await page.scrollToTop()
    await page.pdf({ format: 'letter', path: "test.pdf", printBackground: true })
    await page.close()

}

async function autoScroll(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0
            var distance = 100
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight
                window.scrollBy(0, distance)
                totalHeight += distance

                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                    clearInterval(timer)
                    resolve()
                }
            }, 400)
        })
    })
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true,
      defaultViewport: {
        width: 1366,
        height: 768,
      },
      args: [
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      ]
    })
    await processSite(browser)

    console.log("Finished processing site")

})()
```

**Output**

```js
Processing web site
about to scroll entire site
scrolled entire site
about to look for element
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Loop click
Finished clicking
Scrolling to top
Scrolled to top
saving to pdf
saved to pdf
Closing page
Finished processing site
```

You can see it finds and clicks on 12 elements, but there are many more.  When I watch the browser in GUI mode, these 12 elements are in the bottom pages of the site.   I can watch it actually go click on the elements and expand the comments, but it does not go recursively through all the pages.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clean the console.log() lines from the code? It looks a bit messy.

Comment: I can do that, but I was using them give my self some sort of visual indicator that the code was (or wasn't executing)

Comment: You should clean the code so others can see properly and help you better.

Comment: I think I have the console.log() all removed now.  sorry for the delay -- work gets in the way of the fun stuff some times!

Answer (score 0):

### Issues:

- Check if `delay` is available inside page.evaluate.
- `.forEach` and `.click()` won't work well together due to their asynchronous nature.

### Solution:

Use page.$$(selector) to get the elements to click, and for...of loop to click them recursively. You will also have `delay` or `page.waitFor` available on the node context.

Here is a sample code of how it might look like,

```
const elements = await page.$$(selector);
for(let elementHandle of elements){
  await elementHandle.click()
  await page.waitFor(10000)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was actually just reading about page.$$(selector) and am testing it now.  Fingers crossed!

Comment: I can't post this comment cleanly for some reason.  sorry.
new code:  

console.log("scrolled entire site")
console.log("about to look for element")
const comments = await page.$$('._commentToggleBtn')
await delay(10000)
for (let comment of comments) {
    await comment.click()
    console.log("Loop click")
    await page.waitFor(10000)
 }
 console.log("Finished clicking?")

output:

scrolled entire site
about to look for element
Loop click <- repeated 13 times
Finished clicking?
Finished processing site

it doesn't seem to be going back recursively.

Comment: @haplesscoder, you can update your question and add the new code at the bottom of it, just be sure to make a note about it.

Comment: posting update to original question with new code & output.  Thanks!